# How to get IPv4 address when using SOCKS over ssh

Tags: ssh, proxy, socks, sshd

I'm using SOCKS5 over ssh. All works fine, however, when I check my public IP address, I see this is an IPv6 address (The machine I'm connecting to has both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses). If I understand this correctly this is the responsibility of `sshd_config` on the server I'm using for SOCKS, right? Is it possible somehow to force this to use IPv4 address?

Comment: *"I see this is an IPv6 address"* ... how, where?

Comment: When I check https://www.whatismyip.com/ (in my local browser) I see server's IPv6 address.

Comment: It is a browser, what is connecting using the IPv6 address.

Comment: How come? My computer does not even have any IPv6 address (I disabled this on system level).

Comment: But the browser does DNS queries over the SOCKS5, gets AAAA records and connects over the socks to the IPv6 addresses. It is not using system networking stack.

Comment: Firefox has an option to disable IPv6 in the browser. In `about:config` search for `network.dns.disableIPv6`. http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.dns.disableIPv6 Also if you have control over the ssh server you could alter the config to prefer IPv4 only. The directive is `AddressFamily` and the values are `any`, `inet` (IPv4), `inet6` (IPv6). http://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config

Answer (score 1):

What you can try to do is force SSHD into the IPv4 only mode, by setting:

AddressFamily inet

in your `sshd_config`

> **AddressFamily**
>
> Specifies which address family should be used by sshd(8). Valid arguments are ''any'', ''inet'' (use IPv4 only), or ''inet6'' (use IPv6 only). The default is ''any''.

man [sshd_config](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config)  (OpenSSH)